# What is the best way to get a specific CocoaPod's version at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm currently trying to create a way to log the current version of my Pod at runtime, there are a few ways that come to mind, but I wanted to ask here to make sure i'm not missing something obvious.

What I've done so far:

- Found out that Cocoapods generates an `myPod-umbrella.h` header file that exports the following :

  ```
  FOUNDATION_EXPORT double myPodVersionNumber;
  FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char myPodVersionString[];
  ```

  They Only `myPodVersionNumber` seems to be accessible, and it always has 1.0 for some reason, is there a way to get that working right since i have a feeling that this is the proper way but i have misconfigured it.
- Attempt to get a hold of the built framework's Info.plist and read the version there, but this seems to be a bit problematic, i have no guarantee what a developer will end up doing with the pod and might end up with a different location of the bundle, or even have it unaccessible to the project.
- Create a hardcoded property with the version number, this obviously works, but it adds lots of room to error and does not really feel like the right way to implement this, but if there is no other way to get around CocoaPods, i might just have to do that.
- Have a Build step that will read the PodSpec and generate a simple class that contains metadata about the Pod, feels a bit better than the previous point, but still feels a bit overkill for what i'm looking for.

Does anyone have a better idea or can point me in the right direction ?

What i'm trying to achieve is to be able to run something like this

`print("Current version: \(myPod.version)`")

and have it log it out properly in the console

`#Current version: 1.2.0`

Comment: Have you looked at reading the data from the `Podfile.lock` file instead? This lists all the versions of installed Pods.

Comment: I need to do that during runtime, that's my main issue

Comment: What did you do? I know it has been 6 years since this question is asked though

Answer (score 4):

What about using URLForResource? Prints nicely at runtime with the print statement you asked for.

[image]

This version prints the entire lock file to the console.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("/lockfilefolder/Podfile", withExtension: "lock")!
    let data = try! String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(data)   
}

/* Prints */
// PODS:
// - Firebase/Analytics (3.3.0):
// - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.2.1)
// - Firebase/Auth (3.3.0):
// - Firebase/Analytics (= 3.3.0)
// - FirebaseAuth (= 3.0.3)
// - Firebase/Core (3.3.0):
// - Firebase/Analytics (= 3.3.0)
// - Firebase/Database (3.3.0):
// - Firebase/Analytics (= 3.3.0)
// - FirebaseDatabase (= 3.0.2)
// TL;DR
```

This next version prints specific line numbers. By using  `componentsSeparatedByString("-")` I am able to remove the `-` character before the pod name so it looks cleaner. This works because lock files use `-` on every line in the list of pod names. Notice we are using **`pathForResource`** not **`URLForResource`** here.

```
    do {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("/lockfilefolder/Podfile", ofType: "lock"){
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let lockFileData = data.componentsSeparatedByString("-")
            print("Current version: \(lockFileData[6])")
        }
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
    }

/* Prints */
// Current version: - Firebase/Core (3.3.0):
```

This next version we print two lines. We are using the `data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())` method. It gets verbose to remove the `-` in this case therefore it's not worth it.

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("/lockfilefolder/Podfile", withExtension: "lock")!
    let data = try! String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let lockFileData = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
    print(lockFileData[72])
    print(lockFileData[6])

/* Prints */
// COCOAPODS: 0.39.0
// - Firebase/Core (3.3.0):
```

Comment: @mostafatorbjørnberg Hi. Is my answer ok? The code gives you a print statement logging any line you wish to the console at runtime. Just place the lockfile in your project and that's it.

Comment: Hi @tymac, thanks for your response, it sounds fine and it'll surely work, but it's not a "proper" solution per say, it's a workaround for something that seems to be missing IMO, I also would not like to add the Podfile to the project since it's not directly related to my own project and i want it to live outside XCode, if there's no official solution i'll just go with a build script that parses that file and adds sort of `podsVersions.json` file that then I can use in my project

Answer (score 2):

1

```
let version = Bundle(for: type(of:PODClass)).object(forInfoDictionaryKey:"CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
```

2

```
if let bundle = Bundle.allFrameworks.first(where: { $0.bundleIdentifier?.contains("POD bundleIdentifier or part") ?? false } ) {
    let version = bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey:"CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
}
```

3

```
if let url = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("Frameworks/PODName.framework") {
    let version = Bundle(url: url)?.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get it via the CFBundleShortVersionString of the Bundle it's a part of.

For example, if you are using a Pod called `FaultyTower`, which has a file called `Basil.swift`, you can do

```swift
var version: String? {
    Bundle(for: Basil.self).infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
}
```

to get the version string of `FaultyTower` pod.