# Getting Realm Version in Code

Tags: swift, realm

Two part question:

How does one get the currently installed version of Realm in code? Swift 3, macOS. I was unable to location any Realm.version property - perhaps I overlooked it.

In a related question

What is the solution to upgrade Realm to the latest version within a project? After updating CocoaPods to the latest, and refreshing, pod install doesn't appear to update Realm. I have 2.0.3 installed and 2.2.0 is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're embedding Realm Swift as a dynamic framework directly, the version number is contained in the framework's info.plist file. It should be possible to access the plist during runtime; there's a few [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538215/get-version-number-of-ios-universal-framework-in-client) discussing this.

Since CocoaPods creates dynamic frameworks for Swift, the above approach of accessing the info plists should work, but if it doesn't there might be [other ways to access versions of pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300945/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-specific-cocoapods-version-at-runtime).

In any case, I would definitely recommend you review why you're wanting to check the version numbers of your libraries. It's better practice to check a framework's capabilities at runtime (eg, testing a class you need exists etc) than to directly use the version number.

For your second question, you need to run `pod update RealmSwift` to get CocoaPods to check for an updated version of Realm.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer. The update to RealmSwift worked perfectly. As far as the version goes - I was simply using it for reference during development to reference what version is installed. All of our classes are tested before using and nothing rely's on the version number - other than our eyes seeing it.